# When adding new jQuery functions into the DOM how do I get them to communicate with already loaded functions?

Tags: jquery

I have searched quite a bit on the web and on this site and can't seem to find an answer. If it's already been asked I apologize in advance. I have a page [*index.htm*] where I load an external javascript file that contains generic functions [*func.js*].  The function I am calling in *func.js* is **show_message()**.

How I am loading the JS file into *index.htm*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/func.js"></script>
```

---

Now, I have some page specific JS code in *index.htm* that calls the external function **show_message()**.  This call is executed successfully. Also on *index.htm* I have an AJAX call that adds an external page [*external.htm*] into the DOM. The *external.htm* has some page specific js code as well. One of the functions in *external.htm* references **show_message()**.

After the contents of external.htm are added into the DOM the javascript code written in external.htm can not access **show_message()**. I assume it is because we added *external.htm* to the DOM after the initial load. The question is how can I get the js code we just added to the DOM to access the js code that was loaded initially?

The jQuery function [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) comes pretty close to what I want except I'm not trying to assign a behavior to the newly added DOM elements. I want the JS that was just added to the DOM to have access to functions defined on the page load.

Thoughts? Am i making any sense?

Thanks,

Nick

**Edit** I am using the jQuery mobile framework. That is why to load external.htm all you see in the link tag on the index.htm page.

---

**func.js**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    //function for displaying message box
    function show_message(currentPage, message, type, back_url)
    {
        $("p.message_text",currentPage).html(message);
        $(".message_box img",currentPage).attr("src","/_assets/img/icon-" + type + ".png");
        if(back_url != false)
        {
            $(".close_message",currentPage).attr("href", back_url); 
        }
        $(".message_wrapper",currentPage).css("display","block");
        $(".message_box",currentPage).css("display","block");
    }   

}); //end jQuery
```

---

**index.htm** (snippet)

```
<a href="/external.htm">External</a>
```

---

**external.htm** (snippet)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#fdbck_form").submit(function(){

      var feedback_text = $("#feedback-text").val();
      var currentPage = $('#feedback');

      //check minimal length of searching parameter
      if(feedback_text.length == 0)
      {
        //show error message
        show_message(currentPage,'required','warning',false);
        return false;
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: Your question makes sense, but snippets of index.htm and external.htm would certainly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your edit, you can see that `show_message` is defined within a function callback. This is a problem, because functions are defined in the current scope. They are not defined in the global scope.  So when you define `show_message`, it is only available in the context of that particular anonymous function.  You cannot access it from the other file, or indeed from outside the anonymous function in *that* file.

The only realistic way around this is to define it in some global context.  If you only have the one function where this is needed, this is fairly easy: just stick the function definition outside the callback function, in the global scope, and it will be accessible everywhere.

If you have multiple functions that need to be global, it would be best to namespace them with a single global object, because it's not good practice to clutter the global namespace with functions.  This would look something like this:

```
myProject = {};
myProject.show_message = function(currentPage, message, type, back_url) {
    // function body
};
myProject.hide_message = function(currentPage, message) {
    // function body
};
```

Then you could access these methods from anywhere using `myProject.show_message()`.